# Conformal mapping of the disk $| z | <R_1$ to disk $| w | <R_2$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

could you help me with the following please:

Find the conformal mapping of the disk $| z | <R_1$ to disk $| w | <R_2$ such that $w (a) = b, Arg(w´(a)) = \alpha $, $(| a | <R_1, | b | <R_2)$.

I have tried the following, but it does not match the solution that comes in the book:
We go to the unit circle with $w_1=\frac{z}{R_1}$, and then to the radio $R_2$ with $w_2=R_2 w_1$ and the transformation we are looking for is then its composition, I do not know how to make the conditions are fulfilled. I would greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : What are the complex automorphisms of the disk ? Could they be used to fulfill the conditions ?

Comment: you mean to $e^{i\alpha} \frac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0} z}$?

Comment: @Haus Yes, something like that. Can you use such an automorphism to "correct" your initial map ?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried that way, but I do not understand how to make it comply with the conditions that are asked of me ...

Comment: If you assume $R_1 = R_2 = 1$, can you find a conformal mapping that sends $a$ to $b$ ?

Comment: I have tried, but it did not come to anything, I am new to the subject, I have read enough, but I do not give. Thank you very much, any book that you can recommend me for this?